# How to check that the value of a column start like the value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

I have two variables, `ID` and `proyect` (`ID NUMBER(3,0)`, `proyect VARCHAR2(4)`). I want the value of `proyect` to start like the value of `ID`, but adding a letter P at the end. For example if, `ID` is `000`, I want `proyect` to be `000P`.

To check that they are the same, I would do `CHECK (ID = proyect)` and to check that it ends with a letter P I would do `CHECK (proyect LIKE '%P')`

I don't know how to combine the two of them.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to create `proyect` as a generated column, so it *always* follows the format.  But that is not the question you asked.  You can just use:

```
check (proyect = ID || 'P')
```